# How does Snapchat save videos with overlays Android?

Tags: android, video, android-camera, android-videoview, snapchat

I am adding some Snapchat like functionality to my app and my understanding is that when taking a photo Snapchat just takes a screenshot of the photo with the text or the stickers or whatever and sends it. I am able to replicated that fine.

Where I am struggling is how on earth are they saving the overlays like text and stickers for videos?

Any ideas?

Comment: Custom made? http://petapixel.com/2016/06/30/snapchats-powerful-facial-recognition-technology-works/

Comment: So, did you find anything ?